Dependency Injection C#, pass parameter
How to correctly use DI to create objects that have a parameter in the constructor? E.g. int Id.
public class SomeClass
{
  public SomeClass(int id)
  {
    Id = id;
  }
  public int Id {get;}
}

Consider the ini file in which the list of Ids is stored. I would like read these value and for each create instance of SomeClass with specific id.
List<int> ids = readIdsFromIni();
foreach(var id in ids)
{
   ???
}

And I assume somewhere should be registration of SomeClass somethink like this
var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(e.Args);
builder.Services.AddTransient<SomeClass>();

At now I use for theses cases Abstract Factory but in this factory I use direct call of new SomeClass(id);
Thank you
Petr

How are you planning to consume them?

That strongly depends on the architecture you are planning for your app.
You could implement some service, which returns the needed ID for your "SomeClass" to use. Then you would inject this service into "SomeClass". But that's just an idea, i don't know your use case.

If the sample with the ini file is close enough to the reality you want to implement, then you may want to consider the configuration concept, where the whole ini file is parsed and deserialized into the objects graph, and then you register something like IConfiguration, which provides access to the objects from such a graph.

By Serg advice,
I tried it's look like right concept bellow

Create service for provide Id

    public class ProviderId
    {
       public int GetNextId()
       {
          ...
       }
    }


Register of SomeClass

    builder.Services.AddSingleton<ProviderId>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<SomeClass>((serviceProvider)=>
    {
      var idProvider = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ProviderId>();
      var id = idProvider.GetNextId();
      return new SomeClass(id);
    });

Thank you
Petr

So upon every resolution you will get a "random" id? Are you implementing some kind of sharding/round-robin?

The implementation of GetNextId will read for example row from ini file and return value  of Id. Each call of this method will shift to next row. There willl be necessary to know count of ids.

What if there are 2 rows and 10 classes which want to resolve the dependency?

It will produce propably some exception in idProvider, but it is not my case. I need create for each row one class not more.

Your description is missing a lot of information, so it's difficult to understand how you'll be using these, but you could do something like this -
foreach (int id in ids)
{
    builder.Services.AddSingleton(serviceProvider => new SomeClass(id))
}

This will register one implementation of SomeClass for each of the IDs you've read from the file. Notice that this will not actually create the instances, they will only be created once (and if) they are needed in order to satisfy some other requirement. For example, you could have a service with a constructor that looks something like this -
public class MyService
{
    public MyService(IEnumerable<SomeClass> things)
    {
        // in here, "things" will contain instances for all
        // of the implementations you've registered
    }
}


Thank you for response, but I think it is not good for my case., because this concept need read all id from ini file for register to Services. I think this registration should be on one place somewhere on start program and I prefer it will be divide from some reading from ini etc.
